# How to remove myself from all websites that show whois history?

Tags: whois, privacy

It's easy to find Whois Information from the past (Whois History or called Reversed Whois) from sites like;

- domaintools.com
- reg.com
- 12whois.com
- domainhistory.com
- whoismind.com

some are cheap and pay per search starting from $1 to even some sites where you need to become a member with paid subscription.

How can I have 2 of my domains removed from those services?

Comment: Once information is public it is very hard to remove it from everywhere.  You probably can't do it.   The best you may be able to do is follow the advice in Bhargav Joshi's answer for your next domain.

Answer (score 1):

You can purchase Domain Privacy which is sold additionally by your DNS provider. Domain Privacy will mask your details and hide your essential information appearing publicly.

Comment: Domain Privacy is typically an option offered by the **registrar** of the domain name (which can be completely unrelated to the DNS provider) and it might be sold or offered. You could as well use the service of any third pary (not the registrar, and not a DNS provider).

Comment: Some registrars provide domain privacy free, and some of those are on by default.